# Is there a way to speed up Hive queries with Python

Tags: python, hive, pyspark, kerberos

I am currently using `Pyhive` to connect to our `Hiveserver2` which is authenticated by `Kerberos`.

```
conn = hive.Connection(host=HIVE_HOST,
                           port=HIVE_PORT,
                           database=HIVE_DB,
                           auth='KERBEROS',
                           kerberos_service_name="hive")
```

I mainly read from this table that has time series data (10 second interval) for hundreds of tags using the following query:

```
sql = """
select dt, 
max(case when tag_id = 'tag1' then val end) as tag1,
max(case when tag_id = 'tag2' then val end) as tag2,
max(case when tag_id = 'tag3' then val end) as tag3,
max(case when tag_id = 'tag4' then val end) as tag4,
.....
.....
from (

    select tag_id,
        cast(concat(year_mon_day,' ',lpad(hour_val,2,'0'),':',lpad(minute_val,2,'0'),
               ':',lpad(second_val,2,'0')) as timestamp) dt,
        val
    from tag_data
    where cast(year_mon_day) as date) >= '2018-09-01'
    and cast(year_mon_day) as date) < '2018-09-15'
) sub
group by dt
"""
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
results = cur.fetchall()
```

This query takes about 40 minutes to return ~100,000 rows with 400+ columns. And this is just 15 days worth of data. Ultimately we need to pull months or years data at a time for machine learning.

I wonder if there is a way to speed up `pyhive` query. I know it is `sqlalchemy` under the hood but is the query run in parallel depending on the available resource? We have a pretty good HPC resource to use. How do I run it faster?

Should I use `PySpark` and run `SparkSQL` for query instead? However I can't seem to find how to connect to hive2+kerberos with PySpark.